# How to additionally configure autocreated Spring Boot beans?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Is there a standard way of configuring already created bean in Spring Boot by NOT creating providing this bean myself but instead somehow injecting this bean in a hook method in a configuration class and do additional class?

For example I would like to have Thymeleaf's `TemplateResolver` as created by its autoconfiguration but I would like to change one property.

What is the best way to do this (again, not by providing my own `TemplateResolver` ) ?

Answer (score 9):

You could `@Autowired` the auto-configured `TemplateResolver` into your configuration class and then use a `@PostConstruct` method to set the property.

```
public class ExampleConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private TemplateResolver templateResolver;

    @PostConstruct
    void customize() {
        templateResolver.setFoo("bar");
    }

}
```

Comment: Although this might work, wouldn't this be a futile attempt for instance when a bean also implements `InitializingBean` (or has a `@PostConstruct` method)? As setting the property might be too late by then as the bean is already fully prepared.

Comment: @M.Deinum The question was specifically about `TemplateResolver` which is neither an `InitializingBean` nor annotated with `@PostConstruct`. A `BeanPostProcessor` could be a more general solution, but it's more complicated than the approach I've described above.

Comment: I agree, but I was asking/stating it just to prevent others from using this as a general solution. I generally create a `BeanPostProcessor` for this (which saved me in a few cases especially when wanting to update/modify default configured beans using a namespace or `@Enable*` annotation).

Answer (score 1):

I was facing a similar issue, I needed to customize an autoconfigured bean. Thanks to M. Deinum and Andy Wilkinson, I coded a BPP based on your points. Hope it can be a more general solution for this kind of issue.

```
public class TemplateResolverCustomizationBeanPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor, Ordered {
    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());
    private int order = Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE;

    public TemplateResolverCustomizationBeanPostProcessor() {
        logger.info("Created TemplateResolverCustomizationBeanPostProcessor instance");
    }

    @Override
    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName)
            throws BeansException {
        logger.info("postProcessBeforeInitialization method invoked");
        return bean;
    }

    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName)
            throws BeansException {
        logger.info("postProcessAfterInitialization method invoked");
        if (bean instanceof TemplateResolver) {
            ((TemplateResolver) bean).setFoor("bar");
        }
        return bean;
    }

    public void setOrder(int order) {
        this.order = order;
    }

    @Override
    public int getOrder() {
        return order;
    }
}
```